# Get name of a class from where the function was called in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have two separate classes where one of them is a logging class.  I would like to be able to tell which class is calling the log class functions without passing any parameters.

```php
<?php
class Log {
    public function general($message) {
        // Tell which class/function is calling this function here
        $class = get_called_class();

        echo 'Your message was: "'.$message.'" from class: "'.$class.'"';
    }
}

class foo {
    public function log_something() {
        $Log = new Log();
        $Log->general('Hello, world!');
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->log_something();

?>
```

The output I would like is: `Your message was "Hello, world!" from class "foo"`

However, the message I'm getting is:
`Your message was "Hello, world!" from class "Log"`

Am I missing something, or doing something wrong?

Comment: I think log may be a reserved word in PHP, trying changing your class name.

Comment: If `log` were a reserved word, he would have gotten an error in the way he is using it.

Comment: That's right, the Log class does not interfere with the log() function that comes with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer to my problem by using `debug_backtrace()`

```php
<?php
class Log {
    private function get_call_class() {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

        $classes = array();
        foreach ($backtrace as $item) {
            if ($item['class'] != '' && $item['class'] != 'Log') $classes[] = $item['class'];
        }
        return $classes[0];
    }

    public function general($message) {
        // Tell which class/function is calling this function here
        $class = $this->get_call_class();

        echo 'Your message was: "'.$message.'" from class: "'.$class.'"';
    }
}


class foo {
    public function log_something() {
        $Log = new Log();
        $Log->general('Hello, world!');
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->log_something();

?>
```

Explanation: The `Log->get_call_class()` function gets information from `debug_backtrace()` and loops through it to find the classes that don't have the name of 'Log' or blank names then returns the first result, which  is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You just creating the `Log` object inside of `Foo`, therefore your `get_called_class()` call will always result in `Log`. You need to make `Foo` inherit `Log` if you want that kind of behavior. For example:

```
<?php

class Log {
    public function msg($message) {
        // Tell which class/function is calling this function here
        $class = get_called_class();

        echo 'Your message was: "'.$message.'" from class: "'.$class.'"';
    }
}

class Foo extends Log {
  public function doSomething() {
    $this->msg( 'Hello World!' );
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->doSomething();
```

Outputs:

`Your message was: "Hello World!" from class: "Foo"`